# echo redirecting string for diff operation

Tags: bash, scripting, diff, sh

I have content that need to be compared in two variables - res1 and res2

```
compRes=`diff -W999 --side-by-side <(echo ${res1}) <(echo ${res2})`
```

Throwing some error

```
command substitution: line 435: syntax error near unexpected token `('
command substitution: line 435: `diff -W999 --side-by-side <(echo ${res1}) <(echo ${res2})'
```

Tried - Double quote as well

```
compRes=`diff  -W999 --side-by-side <(echo "$res1") <(echo "$res2")`
```

Same Error:

```
command substitution: line 435: syntax error near unexpected token `('
command substitution: line 435: `diff  -W999 --side-by-side <(echo "$res1") <(echo "$res2")'
```

What could be the issue?

**Some additional information (Strange):**

```
File: test.sh

    file1="Simple.csv"
    file2="SimpleWithAddedLine.csv"

    res1=$(cut -d, -f1-2 $file1)
    res2=$(cut -d, -f1-2 $file2)
    compRes=`diff -W999 --side-by-side <(echo "$res1") <(echo "$res2") | sed '/^[^\t]*\t\s*|\t\(.*\)/{s//\1 CMPUPDATED/;b};/^\([^\t]*\)\t*\s*<$/{s//\1 CMPDELETED/;b};/^.*>\t\(.*\)/{s//\1 CMPNEW/;b};d'`
    added=$(echo "$compRes" | grep "CMPNEW" | wc -l)
    deleted=$(echo "$compRes" | grep "CMPDELETED" | wc -l)
    updated=$(echo "$compRes" | grep "CMPUPDATED" | wc -l)
    let "ttlUpdates = $added + $deleted + $updated"
    echo -e "\nAdded: $added - Deleted: $deleted - Updated: $updated"
    echo -e "Total Changes: $ttlUpdates (Maximum allowed: $maxAllowed)\n"
```

And

```
File: callscript.sh

#!/bin/bash

CORE_SCRIPT_FILE="test.sh"
sh ${CORE_SCRIPT_FILE} | tee "logfile.log"
```

OK, I have two files.
When I call the test.sh - everything goes fine.

```
[batch]$ ./test.sh

Added: 4 - Deleted: 1 - Updated: 1
Total Changes: 6 (Maximum allowed: )
```

At the same time, when I call - callscript.sh file:

```
[batch]$ ./callscript.sh
/abc/test.sh: command substitution: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/abc/test.sh: command substitution: line 6: `diff -W999 --side-by-side <(echo "$res1") <(echo "$res2") | sed '/^[^\t]*\t\s*|\t\(.*\)/{s//\1 CMPUPDATED/;b};/^\([^\t]*\)\t*\s*<$/{s//\1 CMPDELETED/;b};/^.*>\t\(.*\)/{s//\1 CMPNEW/;b};d''
```

Comment: Try double quote `$res1` and `$res2`?

Comment: @whjm - tried double quote too. same error

Comment: What is the shell you are using, I dont see any issue in bash shell.

Comment: mine is bash. Same set of codes works well in different file.

Comment: Is `res1` & `res2` is going to have the data directly or it is filename stored in variable?

Comment: @Kumaresan - Could you please post the value of `$res1` and `$res2`? Or could you just try `v=\`diff <(echo foo) <(echo bar)\``?

Comment: Are you perhaps using an old version that doesn't support process substitution? What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` say *when run by the script* (not on the command line)?

Comment: Also, if this is a part of some script, is your `shebang` set to `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: bash version: 3.00.15(1)-release and 
res1,res2 contains the data to be compared a csv lines and shebang set to bin/bash properly

Answer (score 2):

In `callscript.sh` when you run `test.sh` you are using `sh` but the `<(...)` process substitution syntax is only in bash.   Change the last line to

```
bash ${CORE_SCRIPT_FILE} | tee "logfile.log"
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked.
hope. it won't create any other trouble for other activities present n "test.sh".